# How to force voice recognition into writing out numbers or just printing numerals?

Tags: voice-recognition

One edge case I've found when transcribing notes is that, if I say 1, 2, 4 or 8, it's never clear if they will come up as numbers or as one, two, four, eight or one of their homophones.

Using Dragon NaturallySpeaking I could always rely on saying "numeral (number)," and while I understand voice recognition on Android doesn't bring in the cash, I'd still like to know if there's a command I can put before this, because having "1 do this 2 on the other hand, this 3 summary" allows me to sort my notes a bit better e.g. if something matches the ^1.*\b2\b regex.

Now I have a workaround where I say "zero one" or "zero two," and while that is acceptable, I was wondering if anyone found anything more precise.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a workaround where I say "zero one" or "zero two," and while that is acceptable, I was wondering if anyone found anything more precise.

There currently exists no better workaround as far as I know. Google's  voice typing is very limited in features,  much more limited than Dragon.

Currently, as a general rule, Google's voice typing spells out numbers as digits if more than nine or if preceded by another number.